# Inalienable or irrefutable

Tags: word-usage

I read a sentence in "The Hindu" which was:

Pakistan’s Foreign Minister Shah Mehmood Qureshi has said Jaish-e-Mohammad (JeM) chief Masood Azhar is in Pakistan, and asked India to give “solid inalienable evidence” for action to be taken against him

"Inalienable" means - (of a right) impossible to take away or give up

But does that fit here or should there be "irrefutable" instead?

Comment: People who think themselves important often use grand words without knowing their meanings. Often, their speeches are written by underlings.

Comment: I think this is most likely a mistranslation. *Alienate* and *refute* share the sense of "cancelling" or "abrogating" an existing situation, so it is very easy to imagine that a single word in the FM's native tongue might embrace both meanings in different contexts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think "inalienable" is simply a mistake. I cannot see any relevant meaning, and "inalienable evidence" gets no hits in any of the corpora I've looked in, or in Google ngrams.